# Visual Basic cannot display textbox information?

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on a vb program, and I am having an error (duh). I'm trying to display the contents of a users input (textbox) in a messagebox, but it's throwing a `System.InvalidCastException'. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub ThirteenButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ThirteenButton1.Click
    ' withdrawBtn
    If IsNumeric(withdrawTxtBox.Text) Then
        If Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) > Val(My.Settings.accountBalanceBA) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error: You can not withdraw " + withdrawTxtBox.Text + ", you only have " + My.Settings.accountBalanceBA.ToString + ".")
        ElseIf Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) < Val(My.Settings.accountBalanceBA) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully withdrawn $" + Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) + ". Your remaining balance is $" + Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) - My.Settings.accountBalanceBA.ToString)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Entering a number > the account balanceBA will work with no error, but once I enter a number < the balance, it throws the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little advise.. Just avoid using plus sign (+) when performing concatenation, specially when you have mathematical condition to concat with string. You can use "&" instead for concatenation.

Replace plus sign with "&" for best practices.

To correct your code.. you can remove the `.ToString` or place the `.ToString` out the subtraction.. after closing parenthesis. `).ToString` You have to be careful in using parenthesis to avoid unexpected result or worst will encounter an error.

```
    MessageBox.Show("Successfully withdrawn $" & Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) & ". Your remaining balance is $" & Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) - My.Settings.accountBalanceBA)

    MessageBox.Show("Successfully withdrawn $" & Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) & ". Your remaining balance is $" & (Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) - My.Settings.accountBalanceBA).ToString
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am new to vb, and I'm just working on projects to help me train/get code down to memory. This helped!

Comment: Good tip, I had forgotten about that (been quite a while since I worked with VB).

Comment: @EricJ. Thanks :) i used vb.net on my work, and my Senior. advise me that years ago..

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
   MessageBox.Show("Successfully withdrawn $" + Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) + ". Your remaining balance is $" + Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) - My.Settings.accountBalanceBA.ToString)
```

Specifically

```
Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) - My.Settings.accountBalanceBA.ToString
```

is trying to subtract a string from a number.  Use parenthesis to get the order of operations right.

```
(Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text) - My.Settings.accountBalanceBA).ToString
```

Comment: '" Your remaining balance is " + Val(My.Settings.accountBalanceBA.ToString) - Val(withdrawTxtBox.Text))'     Tried this, and I thought val() converted from string --> integer?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert it to an integer to subtract from it My.Settings.accountBalanceBA.